# Multiple Views in ScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, uiview, uiscrollview

I am trying to make a survey app. There are 20 views in one scroll view and lots of uitextviews. When I am trying to do it, the app works very slow. I think I can't make memory management correctly. Can you help me to do it right? Thank you very much. Here is my code:

```
 -(void)textViewBicimle: (UITextView *)textAlani{
[textAlani.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0] CGColor]];
[textAlani.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
  }

  - (void) tableCiz:(NSMutableArray *)hucreler sutun:(int)sutunSayisi satir:     (int)satirSayisi{
 int z = 0;
 for (int i =0;i<satirSayisi;i++){
     for(int j=0;j<sutunSayisi&&z<satirSayisi*sutunSayisi;j++,z++){
         [self textViewBicimle:[hucreler objectAtIndex:z]];
         [[hucreler objectAtIndex:z] setFrame:CGRectMake((20+j*100), (20+i*40), 100, 40)];
     }
 }
 }

 -(void)hucreArrayOlustur: (int)sutunSayisi suankiView:(UIView *)soruViewIki satir:(int)satirSayisi{
for (int i = 0; i <sutunSayisi*satirSayisi; i++){
    self.textView = [[UITextView alloc]init];
    self.textView.text = @"dsgfdh";
    [self.hucreArray addObject:self.textView];
    [soruViewIki addSubview:self.textView];
    [self.textView release];
}
}

-(void)viewOlustur{
 for (int i = 0; i <soruAdedi; i++){
self.hucreArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
if (i == 0){
    self.soruView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 728, 0)];
    self.soruView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.soruView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self hucreArrayOlustur:5 suankiView:self.soruView satir:10];
    [self tableCiz:self.hucreArray sutun:5 satir:10];
    CGRect frame = self.soruView.frame;
    CGRect frame2 = [[self.hucreArray objectAtIndex:49] frame];
    frame.size.height =  frame2.origin.y+frame2.size.height+34;
    self.soruView.frame = frame;
    [self.viewArray addObject:self.soruView];
    [scrollView addSubview:self.soruView];
    [self.soruView release];
}
else{
    CGRect frameGecici = [[self.viewArray objectAtIndex:i-1] frame];
    float geciciY = frameGecici.origin.y+frameGecici.size.height+1;
    self.soruView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, geciciY, 728, 0)];
    self.soruView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.soruView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self hucreArrayOlustur:5 suankiView:self.soruView satir:10];
    [self tableCiz:self.hucreArray sutun:5 satir:10];
    CGRect frame = self.soruView.frame;
    CGRect frame2 = [[self.hucreArray objectAtIndex:49] frame];
    frame.size.height =  frame2.origin.y+frame2.size.height+34;
    self.soruView.frame = frame;
    [self.viewArray addObject:self.soruView];
    [scrollView addSubview:self.soruView];
    [self.soruView release];
}

}
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 10000);
self.viewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[self viewOlustur];
NSLog(@"%@",self.viewArray);
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 - (void)dealloc {
 [self.soruView release];
 [self.textView release];
 [scrollView release];
 [super dealloc];
 }

 - (void)viewDidUnload {
 [self setScrollView:nil];
 [super viewDidUnload];
  }
  @end
```

Comment: Is that what they call Hungarian notation?

Answer (score 0):

The following advice from the [UIScrollView reference page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) may help:

> The object that manages the drawing of content displayed in a scroll
>   view should tile the content’s subviews so that no view exceeds the
>   size of the screen. As users scroll in the scroll view, this object
>   should add and remove subviews as necessary.

So, if you've got one big survey view inside your scroll view, and many question views each with multiple views inside the survey view, you could for example eliminate the survey view and lay out just the visible questions in the scroll view's content view.

Comment: The problem is when I add the views in to the scrollview the app works too slow. I think it fills up the memory.
@Caleb

Comment: Right -- that's why you want to limit the views to just those that are visible. As the user scrolls, you'll remove some and add others, depending on the direction of the scrolling.

Comment: Do you know how can i do that? While scrolling remove views and add others. Is there a delegate or something?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html this will inform you as the user scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are talking about memory management, I would like to correct a few things here just for the sake of best memory management practices.

You should not use,

```
self.textView = [[UITextView alloc]init];
```

Instead use it as,

```
self.textView = [[[UITextView alloc] init] autorelease];
```

And do not use `[self.textView release];` directly on a property. If you are not using ARC, you can put the below line in your dealloc method,

```
self.textView = nil;
```

And in case if you can put some variable as local variable, you dont need to use it as a property.

Instead of,

```
self.soruView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 728, 0)];
```

probably you can use it as,

```
UIView *soruView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 728, 0)];
//rest of the code here
[self.scrollView addSubview:soruView];
[soruview release];
```

And in case you dont need to make all the views visible at the same time, you can add rest of the views as and when user scrolls to that point. This should also help in optimizing memory usage.